# simple loop in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I have this code:

```
count = $content.find('.post').length;              
for x in [1...count]
    /*
    prev_el_height += $("#content .post:nth-child(" + x + ")").height();
    */
    prev_el_height += $content.find(".post:nth-child(" + x + ")").height();
```

I expected this to turn into

```
for (x = 1; x < count; x++) { prev_el ... }
```

but it turns into this:

```
for (x = 1; 1 <= count ? x < count : x > count; 1 <= count ? x++ : x--) {
```

<del>Can somebody please explain why?</del>

**EDIT: How do I get my expected syntax to output?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In CoffeeScript, you need to use the `by` keyword to specify the step of a loop. In your case:

```
for x in [1...count] by 1
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You're asking to loop from `1` to `count`, but you're assuming that `count` will always be greater-than-or-equal-to one; the generated code doesn't make that assumption.

So if `count` is >= 1 then the loop counter is incremented each time:

```
for (x = 1; x < count; x++) { /* ... */ }
```

But if `count` is < 1 then the loop counter is decremented each time:

```
for (x = 1; x > count; x--) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you want `x` to go from 1 to `count`. The code is checking whether `count` is bigger or smaller than 1.

If `count` is bigger than 1, then it has to *increment* `x` while it is *smaller* than `count`.

If `count` is smaller than 1, then it has to *decrement* `x` while it is *bigger* than `count`.

Comment: Your question originally was **WHY?**

Comment: Yes I realise that but I though people would provide the solution as well, but thanks :) I gave you +1 now anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

```
$('#content .post').each ->
    prev_el_height += $(this).height()
```

Has the same effect, assuming `:nth-child` is equivalent to `.eq()`, and `x` going past the number the elements is a typo.

Comment: That's not what I'm doing, I'm adding each div.post's height to the variable prev_el_height which is unique for each div.post ... I know it's not optimal to search for each div every single lap and I'm looking into finding a solution right now..

Comment: I made a $content variable now and did:
`prev_el_height += $content.find(".post:nth-child(" + x + ")").height();`
instead!

Comment: @OZZIE ah, that var is not visible in the code you posted. That's a nice improvement, you could also save the `.post` collection and then filter it.