# CoffeeScript for efficiency

Tags: coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript code

```
for y in [coY - limit .. coY + limit]
    for x in [coX - limit .. coX + limit]
```

I was looking for ways how to improve speed of my code and found what it compiles into:

```
for (y = _i = _ref = coY - limit, _ref1 = coY + limit; _ref <= _ref1 ? _i <= _ref1 : _i >= _ref1; y = _ref <= _ref1 ? ++_i : --_i) {
  for (x = _j = _ref2 = coX - limit, _ref3 = coX + limit; _ref2 <= _ref3 ? _j <= _ref3 : _j >= _ref3; x = _ref2 <= _ref3 ? ++_j : --_j) {
```

When I replaced that with my own JavaScript

```
for(y = coY - limit; y <= coY + limit; y++) {
    for(x = coX - limit; x <= coX + limit; x++) {
```

I have measured the script to be significantly faster (from 25 to 15 ms). Can I somehow force CoffeeScript to compile into code similar to mine? Or is there other solution?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple loop in coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246422/simple-loop-in-coffeescript)

Comment: Yes it is. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find that question before asking this one.

Comment: No worries. It's kind of a tricky question to search for. I doubt I would have found it either if I didn't know exactly what I was looking for. Your duplicate question just means that now there's a better chance someone in the future will happen on the right search terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your loop will always go from a smaller number to a bigger number, you can use `by 1`:

```
for y in [coY - limit .. coY + limit] by 1
    for x in [coX - limit .. coX + limit] by 1
```

Which compiles to:

```
for (y = _i = _ref = coY - limit, _ref1 = coY + limit; _i <= _ref1; y = _i += 1) {
  for (x = _j = _ref2 = coX - limit, _ref3 = coX + limit; _j <= _ref3; x = _j += 1) {
```

It's not **HEAPS** better, but possibly a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I dunno buddy, the code in your edit compiles to this for me:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
var x, y, _i, _j, _ref, _ref1, _ref2, _ref3;

for (y = _i = _ref = coY - limit, _ref1 = coY + limit; _i <= _ref1; y = _i += 1) {
  for (x = _j = _ref2 = coX - limit, _ref3 = coX + limit; _j <= _ref3; x = _j += 1) {
  }
}
```

To get it exactly like you want it, you might just have to actually write it in JavaScript. Luckily, CoffeeScript has syntax for inserting literal JS into a CS file. If you surround JS with backticks (`), the CS compiler will include it in the output but it won't change what's in the backticks in any way.

Here's an example:

```
console.log "regular coffeescript"

#surround inline JS with backticks, like so:
`for(y = coY - limit; y <= coY + limit; y++) {
  for(x = coX - limit; x <= coX + limit; x++) {
    console.log('inline JS!');
  }
}`

console.log "continue writing regular CS after"
```

Source: http://coffeescript.org/#embedded